# How do you add an icon to a OSX console app with XCode 6?

Tags: xcode, macos, icons

I give up, I can't figure it out. I'm new to mac, and this is driving me insane.

The steps outlined here are not sufficient: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/AddingIconSets2.html

The result: the blocky "exec" icon.

What else do I need to do? The .xcassets files I created have been added to the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase. However, the executable isn't any larger.

I also created an .icns file, and I was never able to get that to work either. I think these are deprecated?

Comment: I didn't think it was possible to do. If I were you, I'd wrap it in an application bundle.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Yup you are right.