# How to add Icon to Xcode C++ Project

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode-6.2

Hello I'm new to Xcode and I'm creating a C++ application using "Command Line Tool" Template. Please tell me how can I add an Icon to my C++ application. Also when I'm building the the project I can't find any build folder or executable in the project folder, how do I build the executable for release?

EDIT: Also tell me how can I remove the command prompt completely from my application. Is it possible to remove the command prompt from this type of project

Comment: Why would you need an icon for a *command line* tool?

Comment: The built executable is usually in the `DerivedData` folder (under `DerivedData/Build/Products`), unless you've changed the default settings.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm creating a simple opengl demo and I need to add the icon, is it possible to add the Icon or do I need to use other template to create application with icon.

Comment: @PaulR How do I change it, so that the executable is generated in the build folder under project folder.

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561757/how-do-you-add-an-icon-to-a-osx-console-app-with-xcode-6 : wrap it in an application bundle

Comment: It sounds like "Command Line Tool" is not the template you needed.